# WebAPI: EFMVC + MEF giving same singleton db context on every web call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I am trying to get to grips with WebAPI. I have been looking at the EFMVC project on codplex: http://efmvc.codeplex.com/  I chose to use MEF as my dependency resolver as per this blog http://blogs.realdolmen.com/experts/2012/08/31/mef-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-webapi/ , but testing shows that the DBContext is being re-used across multiple web requests. I had made the assumption that the dependency resolver would give me a new container on each web request, but it seems this is not happening.

I am not really sure how to progress. So here is what I have so far:

MefConfig:

```
    public static class MefConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMef()
    {
        var container = ConfigureContainer();

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MefControllerFactory(container));

        var dependencyResolver = System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver;
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new MefDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static CompositionContainer ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = new CompositionContainer(assemblyCatalog);

        return container;
    }
}

public class MefDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer _container;

    public MefDependencyResolver(CompositionContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        var export = _container.GetExports(serviceType, null, null).SingleOrDefault();

        return null != export ? export.Value : null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        var exports = _container.GetExports(serviceType, null, null);
        var createdObjects = new List<object>();

        if (exports.Any())
        {
            foreach (var export in exports)
            {
                createdObjects.Add(export.Value);
            }
        }

        return createdObjects;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ;
    }
}

public class MefControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly CompositionContainer _compositionContainer;

    public MefControllerFactory(CompositionContainer compositionContainer)
    {
        _compositionContainer = compositionContainer;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        var export = _compositionContainer.GetExports(controllerType, null, null).SingleOrDefault();

        IController result;

        if (null != export)
        {
            result = export.Value as IController;
        }
        else
        {
            result = base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
            _compositionContainer.ComposeParts(result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

My Controller class has it's constructor thus:

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyApiController(ICommandBus commandBus, IMyRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("My Repository cannot be null!");

        if (commandBus == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("CommandBus cannot be null");

        this._repository = repository;
        this._commandBus = commandBus;

    }
```

on a web POST, as per the EFMVC project I make a CreateItemCommand and by calling Submit(CreateItemCommand) on the commandBus the Submit method of the CommandBus is a s follows.

```
    public void Submit<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand
    {
        var handler =    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(ICommandHandler<TCommand>)) as ICommandHandler<TCommand>;
        if (!((handler != null) && handler is ICommandHandler<TCommand>))
        {
            throw new CommandHandlerNotFoundException(typeof(TCommand));
        }
        handler.Execute(command);
    }
```

and an example of the command handler is:

```
[Export(typeof(ICommandHandler<CreateCommand>))]
public class CreateCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateCommand>
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="myRepository">implementation of MyRepository</param>
    /// <param name="unitOfWork">implementation of UnitOfWork</param>
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CreateCommandHandler(IMyRepository myRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        if (myRepository == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("MyRepository cannot be NULL!");

        if (unitOfWork == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("UnitOfWork cannot be NULL!");

        this._myRepository = myRepository;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Actions the Add Item to db
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">CreateCommand pertaining to the given item</param>
    /// <returns>CommandResult indicating success or otherwise</returns>
    public void Execute(CreateCommand command)
    {
        //CommandResult result = null;
        this._myRepository.Add(command.Item);
        this._unitOfWork.SaveChanges();            
    }
}
```

Unit of Work is implemented thus:

```
[Export(typeof(IUnitOfWork))]
[PartCreationPolicy(System.ComponentModel.Composition.CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory;
    private ApiContext dataContext;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public UnitOfWork(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        this.databaseFactory = databaseFactory;
    }

    protected ApiContext DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = databaseFactory.Get()); }
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        DataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Repository is implemented thus:

```
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    private ApiContext dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;
    protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
    {
        DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
        dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    protected ApiContext DataContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
    }

    protected IDbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dbset;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Add(entity);
    }
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Attach(entity);
        dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        dbset.Remove(entity);
    }
    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        IEnumerable<T> objects = dbset.Where<T>(where).AsEnumerable();
        foreach (T obj in objects)
            dbset.Remove(obj);
    }
    public virtual T GetById(Guid id)
    {
        return dbset.Find(id);
    }
    public virtual IQueryable<T> Get()
    {
        return dbset;
    }
}
```

I think I understand why the DB Factory is implemented: it ensures that that UnitOfWork and the commandHandler get the Same context so that in the Command handler the Execute method works.

But since it appears that every web request is getting the Same MEF container,  every web request is getting the same DB factory which is serving a singleton context and thus forcing me to share the context between web calls.

Can anyone guid me as to how I should change this to ensure each web request get's it's on db context?  is EFMVC a bad project to be following if I choose MEF as the container?

[EDIT]
Thinking more on this, I am worried that if the same MEF container is materialising across all web requests,  What happens after a 100,000 requests, will the MEF container now be bloated with references to all the non-shared controller classes MEF has newed up for each request. AS I understand it MEF will olny dispose the objects it creates when we call dispose on the container.

I am clearly misunderstanding something here. Any clarification on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article you referenced it says,

> If you really need a limited scope per request, the “BeginScope”
>   method always needs to return a new object of type IDependencyScope.

Comment: Yeah clearly more research into the dependency resolver is required. so instead of return "this"; should I return "new MefDependencyResolver(ConfigureContainer());"

Comment: Ok, I have marked this as the answer, but I still can't figure out how to make use of MEF and guarantee a new DBContext per request based on the repository pattern and Unit of work, So I have elected to use the Dependency resolver as shown above, and new up a DBContext in each ApiController, that way is not pretty but it will guarantee a new context per request. and since the DBCOntext appears to be an implementation of unit of work, I figure I am not really loosing out by coupling the ORM to the controller instances.